# Android обновление ListFragment заполненного через LoaderManager

Tags: android

Всем привет. Не могу накапать как правильно обновлять ListFragment. Вроде при  заполнение с помощью LoaderManager курсор при изменении базы данных должен обновляться сам, судя из инфы с http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html :

> public abstract void onLoadFinished
> (Loader<D> loader, D data)
>
> Added in API level 11 Called when a
> previously created loader has finished
> its load. Note that normally an
> application is not allowed to commit
> fragment transactions while in this
> call, since it can happen after an
> activity's state is saved. See
> FragmentManager.openTransaction() for
> further discussion on this.
>
> This function is guaranteed to be
> called prior to the release of the
> last data that was supplied for this
> Loader. At this point you should
> remove all use of the old data (since
> it will be released soon), but should
> not do your own release of the data
> since its Loader owns it and will take
> care of that. The Loader will take
> care of management of its data so you
> don't have to. In particular:
>
> The Loader will monitor for changes to
> the data, and report them to you
> through new calls here. You should not
> monitor the data yourself. For
> example, if the data is a Cursor and
> you place it in a CursorAdapter, use
> the
> CursorAdapter(android.content.Context,
> android.database.Cursor, int)
> constructor without passing in either
> FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY or
> FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER (that
> is, use 0 for the flags argument).
> This prevents the CursorAdapter from
> doing its own observing of the Cursor,
> which is not needed since when a
> change happens you will get a new
> Cursor throw another call here.
>
> The Loader will release the data once
> it knows the application is no longer
> using it. For example, if the data is
> a Cursor from a CursorLoader, you
> should not call close() on it
> yourself. If the Cursor is being
> placed in a CursorAdapter, you should
> use the
> swapCursor(android.database.Cursor)
> method so that the old Cursor is not
> closed.

Но он не обновляется, он считывает данные из базы только один раз и при изменении базы данных курсор не обновляется. Максимум, что у меня получилось добиться, это запустить обновление при переключении между вкладками(фрагмент служит содержим одной из вкладок FragmetActivity). Для этого я  инициализировал LoaderManager каждый раз разными ид, через рандомное число. Из более менее осмысленного - пытался перевызывать LoaderManager  в AsynkTask .Еще пробовал adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Но это как и метод тыка и гугл не помогли.

```
public class ChatList extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    final Uri CONTACT_URI = Uri.parse("content://ivied.p001astreamchat/chats");
    String chatName;
    ChatCursorAdapter adapter;
     private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> mCallbacks;
     private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;

     @Override
      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, this.toString());

        String[] from = new String[] { MyContentProvider.MESSAGES_CHANEL, MyContentProvider.MESSAGES_MESSAGE };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ivImg, R.id.tvText };
     // Initialize the adapter.
        adapter = new ChatCursorAdapter(getActivity(), 
                R.layout.message, null, from, to, 0);
     // Associate the (now empty) adapter with the ListView.
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        mCallbacks = this;
        LoaderManager lm = getLoaderManager();
        lm.initLoader(1, null, mCallbacks);

     }

     @Override
     public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

         String [] selectionArgs = new String[] { "67822" };

           Loader<Cursor> mLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), CONTACT_URI, null, "channel = ?",
                    selectionArgs, null);
            return mLoader;

     }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

            // Swap the new cursor in. (The framework will take care of closing the
            // old cursor once we return.)

            adapter.swapCursor(data);
            setListAdapter(adapter); 
            // The list should now be shown.
            if (isResumed()) {
                setListShown(true);
            } else {
                setListShownNoAnimation(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

            // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
            // above is about to be closed. We need to make sure we are no
            // longer using it.
            adapter.swapCursor(null);
        }

}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нашёл 2 решения если есть свой ContenetProvider добавляем строку в метод  public Cursor query:

```
cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                MESSAGES_CONTENT_URI);
```

если нет тогда используем BroadcastReceiver :

```
....

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

.....

newMessage = new BroadcastReceiver() {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                                 LoaderManager lm = getLoaderManager();

                                 lm.restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, mCallbacks);   }};

....
```